# Reveal.Js Causes Scroll Bars on Embedded Object

Tags: scrollbar, tableau-api, reveal.js

I think I have a relatively unique question. For many hours yesterday, I spent a bunch of time trying to figure out how to stop Reveal.Js from causing scroll bars on an embedded object I have. The embedded object is a Tableau Public workbook. You can check it out here: public [dot] tableausoftware.com/views/BudgetBookcampFY14/AdHocDrilldown?:embed=y&:display_count=no

The actual workbook (or dashboard) is sized to width:900 and height: 550. But neither one of those really seem to matter for the purposes of what I'm doing. To embed the object, I use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public [dot] tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js">   
</script>
<div class="tableauPlaceholder" style="width:904px; height:619px;"><noscript>
<a href="#"><img alt="Ad Hoc Drilldown " src="http:&#47;&#47;public.tableausoftware.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Bu&#47;BudgetBookcampFY14&#47;AdHocDrilldown&#47;1_rss.png" style="border: none" />
</a></noscript>
<object class="tableauViz" width="904" height="619" style="display:none;">
<param name="host_url" value="http%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableausoftware.com%2F" /><param name="site_root" value="" /><param name="name" value="BudgetBookcampFY14&#47;AdHocDrilldown" />
<param name="tabs" value="no" /><param name="toolbar" value="yes" />
<param name="static_image" value="http:&#47;&#47;public.tableausoftware.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Bu&#47;BudgetBookcampFY14&#47;AdHocDrilldown&#47;1.png" /><param name="animate_transition" value="yes" />
<param name="display_static_image" value="yes" />
<param name="display_spinner" value="yes" />
<param name="display_overlay" value="yes" /><param name="display_count" value="no" /></object>
</div>
```

Now, the object embeds fine without scroll bars in IE9, Opera, or Google when now using you comment out the div class reveal (   -->). Example: houstonrestaurantinspections [dot] com/budgetbootcamp/minitest.html#/Full-Budget (about 3/4th down the page). That how I want it to render in the presention: no scrollbars on the embedded object.

But, them moment you uncomment the div class and put it back into presentation mode, scrollbars appear around the object: houstonrestaurantinspections [dot] com/budgetbootcamp/test.html#/Ad-Hoc

I've tried changing the object size information, the div class style, the workbook size in tableau, and I've even fiddled a bit with the reveal.js and reveal.min.css, but to no avail. I'm not the best when it comes to sizing all all of the nuisances on CSS (I'm rather a novice on that front, actually), so I could really use some advice here on how to advance this forward. I can chat here, by phone, by e-mail, or even IRC if anyone is willing to devote some time to it with me or provide me some guidance. I suspect it has to do with the way reveal pads an object or a div class or something along those lines, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: You can check out the workbookat:  http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/BudgetBookcampFY14/AdHocDrilldown?:embed=y&:display_count=no

No scroll bars (reveal.js commented out): http://houstonrestaurantinspections.com/budgetbootcamp/minitest.html#/Full-Budget

The reveal.js causing scroll bars at: http://houstonrestaurantinspections.com/budgetbootcamp/test.html#/Ad-Hoc

Comment: So, we've managed to get the scroll bars to disappear in IE, Opera, and Firefox by changing some of the code in reveal.css. Way down on line 201 we did this:

.reveal img,
.reveal video,
.reveal iframe {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}

It used to be 95%.